# Magento 404 in live server

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup, 404

I have completed my Magento application,then for testing purpose i have deploy the files in subfolder (http://domain.com/demo).

After tested the application i like to point exact domain(http://domain.com), so for that i deploy the file to live server and change the core_config table path also.

but after did all the work now the live server show the 404 issue,may i know what is the issue in that.and share your idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: Pls go magento installed root folder and rename \var to \var1 ans check again.

Comment: or find http://domain.com/demo in table core_config_data and replace http://domain.com

Comment: i got answer once cleared the catch in var/catch folder

Answer (score 0):

Upon deployment several actions should be taken:

- Change base url(s) in Magento to live domain(s) - This can be done within the `core_config_data` table by changing the `web/unsecure/base_url` & `web/secure/base_url`
- To allow Magento to reflect these changes `var/cache` & `var/session` should also be cleared.